# Flutter, Stream prints null even if there is data in firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-streambuilder

I tried printing firebase data using stream, but instead of the data I got this in terminal " [ ] ". This means the data is null. But there is data in firebase, how do I solve this problem.

firebase's data
[image]
[image]

stream builder

```
StreamBuilder(
                stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection('paymentData')
                    .snapshots(),
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return const Center(
                      child: Text('Loading'),
                    );
                  }
                  print(snapshot.data!.docs);
                  return ListView(
                      children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((data) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(data['amount']),
                    );
                  }).toList());
                },
              ),
```

Comment: can you add your firebase database

Comment: Most likely spelling mistake in name of collection. Otherwise the code looks good and would run fine. I would suggest adding a condition to check if the status is loading.

Comment: I've shared the screenshots and I think the spelling is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your firebase structure, there is no path called `paymentData`, it is actually a nested sub-collection, so in order to reach `paymentData`, you need to also include the parent of that collection, like this:

```
stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('lender').doc(yourLenderId).collection('paymentData')
        .snapshots(),
```

Get the lender ID from a previus step, which is the id of the document

Comment: Instead of ```yourLenderId``` will I be able to use ```name``` property  in ```paymentData``` sub-collection as doc?

Comment: No, you need to use to use the `ID` of the document which is inside lender, in your case, it's `ganeshsivakumar85@gmail.com`.